# Как организовать применение скрипта на объект в триггере? Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor

Есть несколько однотипных объектов "Дверь". На каждом триггер, который отслеживает "зону действия" закрепленного скрипта. Скрип однообразен, но весит на всех объектах. Собственная реализация, в силу незнания, ужасно топорная... На кнопке взаимодействия 6 скриптов, проверяет триггер каждой двери на сцене. Естественно, что присуща ненужная нагрузка. Цель - реализовать подобную систему: игрок попадает на триггер, и после нажатия кнопки "Взаимодействие" - скрип применяется к объекту, в триггер которого попал игрок.

Скрипт открывания двери:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class OpenDoor : MonoBehaviour {

    public float smooth = 2.0f;
    public float DoorOpenAngle = 90.0f;

    public AudioClip OpenAudio;
    public AudioClip CloseAudio;
    private bool AudioS;

    private Vector3 defaultRot;
    private Vector3 openRot;
    public static bool open;
    public static bool enter;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
            defaultRot = transform.eulerAngles;
            openRot = new Vector3 (defaultRot.x, defaultRot.y + DoorOpenAngle, defaultRot.z);
        }
    
    // Update is called once per frame

        public void playerUse()
    {
        if (enter)
        {
            open = !open;
        }
    }
    void Update () {
        if (open) {
            if (AudioS == false)
            {
                gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(OpenAudio);
                AudioS = true;
            }
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp (transform.eulerAngles, openRot, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
        } else {
            if (AudioS == true)
            {
                gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(CloseAudio);
                AudioS = false;
            }
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp (transform.eulerAngles, defaultRot, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
        }
}

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "Player") {
            enter = true;
            }
        }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.tag == "Player") 
        {
            enter = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Скриншоты:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вам именно по нажатию на дверь нужно открывать ее? или как вы планировали

Answer (score 1):

## Взаимодействие с множеством объектов

### Открываем/закрываем двери, включаем/выключаем свет, взламываем замки и т.д.

---

Вам просто нужен единий интерфейс для взаимодействия с чем угодно.

```
public interface IInteractable 
{
    // указать объекту что он стал/перестал быть целью взаимодействия
    // например что бы показать/убрать его интерфейс
    void SetFocus (bool focus);
    void Interact ();
}
```

---

Дверь как один из объектов взаимодействия просто его реализует. Она знать не должна, что существует какой-то там `Player`.

```
public class Door : MonoBehaviour, IInteractable
{
    [SerializeField] private DoorUI _ui;
    public bool IsOpened { get; private set; }

    public void SetFocus (bool focus)
    {
        _ui.gameObject.SetActive(focus);
    }

    public void Action ()
    {
        if (IsOpened)
            Close();
        else
            Open();
    }

    public void Open ()
    {
        IsOpened = true;
        _ui.SetCloseIcon();
    }

    public void Close ()
    {
        IsOpened = false;
        _ui.SetOpenIcon();
    }
}
```

---

А игрок, как судьект взаимодействий с объектами, сталкиваясь с коллайдерами таких объектов реагирует на них одинаково и совершенно не важно, дверь это или тумбочка, они там сами разберутся.

```
public class InteractionSubject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Action<IInteractable> ObjectEntered;
    public Action<IInteractable> ObjectCameOut;
    private List<IInteractable> _objects = new List<IInteractable>();

    public IEnumerable<IInteractable> Objects => _objects;

    public void ClearObjects ()
    {
        foreach (IInteractable target in _objects)
            target.SetFocus(false);
        _objects.Clear();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter (Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.TryGetComponent(out IInteractable target))
        {
            _objects.Add(target);
            target.SetFocus(true);
            ObjectEntered?.Invoke(target);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit (Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.TryGetComponent(out IInteractable target))
            if (_objects.Remove(target))
            {
                target.SetFocus(false);
                ObjectCameOut?.Invoke(target);
            }
    }
}
```

---

Команду взаимодействия `Action()`, может вызывать UI, включенный по `SetFocus(true)` или другой скрипт, выбирающий объекты из списка `InteractionSubject`.

`IInteractable` можно много чем расширить, событием того, что он перестает быть доступным, именем анимации, которая нужно проиграть при взаимодействии если она есть и т.д.