# общий скрипт для нескольких экземпляров unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня есть объект - сундук и кнопка на канвасе. У сундука есть скрипт, которой при приближении игрока к сундуку должен активировать кнопку, иначе скрывать. Это работает, но до момента, пока сундуков не станет два. В таком случае будет работать только первый, второй же, как я понимаю, тоже пытается активировать кнопку, но первый ему не дает этого сделать. Не понимаю, как это исправить

[image: вот код сундука, который использую]

Comment: [Взаимодействие с множеством объектов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1187332/352119)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как организовать применение скрипта на объект в триггере? Unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1187261/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-unity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше проверяй, не вошёл ли игрок в область где открывается сундук с помощью `OnTriggerEnter2D`.

Для этого создай функцию `OnTriggerEnter2D`, где будешь проверять, не вошёл ли игрок в триггерный коллайдер твоего сундука. Обязательно добавь своему сундуку коллайдер и сделай его триггерным, а также добавь своему игроку тэг `Player`, для того чтобы игра понимала какой объект вошёл в коллайдер сундука.

После добавь функцию `OnTriggerExit2D`, которая проверяет какой объект вышел из коллайдера сундука.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"){
        uim.OpenClose("openChest", true);
    }
}
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Colider2D other){
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"){
        uim.OpenClose("openChest", false);
    }
}
```

В следующий раз как будешь задавать вопрос, **вставляй код текстом а не скриншотом**, чтобы его не приходилось переписывать, особенно если код большой.

Comment: Спасибо. Еще есть вопрос. Когда подходишь к сундуку и нажимаешь кнопку, сундук нужно пометить как открытый (в скрипте сундука есть поле isOpen). Так вот, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, поле менялось именно у того сундука, в котором находится игрок? я додумался только до использования OnTriggerStay2d, но, чтобы сработало, нужно двинуть игрока в любую сторону (тем же translate), чтобы триггер сработал. Мне кажется, это костыльно, есть идея, как такое реализовать?